# How to make no item selected in a listbox on tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

Is there a method to make it so that there are no items selected on a listbox in tkinter? The only idea I have right now is to delete whatever item is selected and then put it back.

Comment: Have you read a tutorial, like [this one](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox.html)?

Answer (score 2):

There's a [`selection_clear()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.selection_clear-method) method for this purpose.

Try this snippet:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

#   root
root = tk.Tk()

#   listbox
listbox = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode='multiple')
listbox.insert('end', *['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
listbox.pack()

#   clear selection button
clear_button = tk.Button(root, text='Clear Selection',
                         command=lambda: listbox.selection_clear(0, 'end'))
clear_button.pack()

#   mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Also, there're some good resources for trivial questions like this:

- [Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html)
- [An Introduction to Tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/)
- [Graphical User Interfaces with Tk (Python docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html)